# Django query - combine two different cases in filter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm using Django 1.10

I have a query that depends on the received parameter - it depends on whether 'job_name' is None or not:

```
def delete_jobs_by_age_and_name(days_ago, job_name=None):

    date_to_delete_from = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_ago

    if job_name is not None:
        jobs_to_delete = AsyncJob.objects.filter(
            name=job_name,
            created_at__lte=date_to_delete_from
    )

    else:
        jobs_to_delete = AsyncJob.objects.filter(created_at__lte=date_to_delete_from)
```

I would like to do that in one query. For example something like:

```
job_name = ANY if job_name is None
jobs_to_delete = AsyncJob.objects.filter(
            name=job_name,
            created_at__lte=date_to_delete_from
    )
```

Is there such option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass your `filter` arguments as a dictionary that you could modify beforehand so you'd only need one `filter` call, and then just unpack the dictionary in the `filter` call. Something like this:

```
filter_kwargs = {'created_at__lte': date_to_delete_from}
if job_name is not None:
    filter_kwargs['name'] = job_name

jobs_to_delete = AsyncJob.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs)
```

Comment: Great idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can compose queries.

```
jobs_to_delete = AsyncJob.objects.filter(created_at__lte=date_to_delete_from)
if job_name is not None:
    jobs_to_delete = jobs_to_delete.filter(name=job_name)
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to run the query only once. Thanks

Comment: This does run the query only once. Querysets are lazy and filter() doesn't actually do any database calls.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the func needs to return the jobs_to_delete value.

The shortest (2 lines) way i can think of is:

```
jobs_to_delete = AsyncJob.objects.filter(created_at__lte=date_to_delete_from)
return jobs_to_delete.filter(name=job_name) if job_name else jobs_to_delete
```

This way you use an 'inline' if statement that would shorten the code written and keep everything readable and simple

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.